# twbs-pagination Start page option is incorrect

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I need some help. I get error when my page count is 0 "Start page option is incorrect"

here is my code

```
$rows = $employee->countData($param);
$per_page = 5;
$pages = ceil( $rows / $per_page );
```

the value of $pages is 0

This is how I get the pages by using jquery.ajax

```
var total_pages = data;
var logid = '30';

$('#pagination')
  .empty()
  .removeData("twbs-pagination")
  .unbind("page");

$('#pagination').twbsPagination({

  totalPages: total_pages,
  visiblePages: 7,
  onPageClick: function (event, page) {
      $('#container').load('load_data.php',{page:page,id:logid});
  }
});

$('#container').load('load_data.php',{id:logid});
```

here is my load_data.php

```
$page = isset($_POST['page']) ? (int) $_POST['page'] : 1 ;

$id = $_POST['id'];

$per_page = 5;

if($page == 0)
    $start = 0;
else
    $start = ( $page - 1 ) * $per_page;


$result = $emp->getPainateData($id,$start,$per_page);
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5):

I've solved a similar issue base on [this solution](https://github.com/esimakin/twbs-pagination/issues/43).
Basically you just need to check the element for twbsPagination, and if it exists destroy it.

```
var total_pages = data;
var logid = '30';

if($('#pagination').data("twbs-pagination"))
  $('#pagination').twbsPagination('destroy');


$('#pagination').twbsPagination({
  totalPages: total_pages,
  visiblePages: 7,
  onPageClick: function (event, page) {
      $('#container').load('load_data.php',{page:page,id:logid});
  }
});

$('#container').load('load_data.php',{id:logid});
```

Answer (score 2):

You need verify if totalPages is higher than zero, this plugin not supported totalPages zero and negative startPage.

One sugestion is: set the totalPages with one case be zero.

You can fix this error by modifying the code like below:

```
   $('#pagination').twbsPagination({
  totalPages: (total_pages==0)?1:total_pages, // make total_pages default as 0
  visiblePages: 7,
  onPageClick: function (event, page) {
      $('#container').load('load_data.php',{page:page,id:logid});
  }
});
```

Comment: Yes correct, totalPages values must be greater than or equal to 1 for avoid this error.

Answer (score 1):

JQuery `TwbsPagination` will return this error if below condition became true: 
`this.options.startPage < 1 || this.options.startPage > this.options.totalPages` 
So as you said 'my page count is 0' this condition will always be true, so you always will see this error. (`startpage` option does not matter)
I hope this helps.